# How to make variable from function in Javascript become global?

Tags: javascript

i use `onclick="namefunction('name')"` on my html

and make a function to catch that:

```
function show(name){
   bobi = name;
}
```

Question.. how to use boby in global? outside that function

Using `window.bobi` isnt working, `globalThis.bobi` isnt working too, declare `var bobi;` on above that function isnt working too.

Sorry i am noob

Comment: Yes declare `var bobi` before the function call

Comment: But think about the process.. What will happen when you access `bobi` before clicking?

Answer (score -1):

Declaring a variable with var makes it global because var is global scope. So if you write like below it should be your answer:

```js
var bobi;
function show(name){
   bobi = name;
}

show('hello world')

console.log(bobi) // it returns 'hello world'
```

Comment: _"Declaring a variable with var makes it global because var is global scope"_ - That's not true...